# Cookies expiring after each session

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-5

My web.config i have set 10 mint for time out

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10" />
```

And my filter as follows

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;

        HttpCookie userInfoCookie =
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Convert.ToString(CookieField.cookieName)]];
        string userExpire = string.Empty;
        userExpire = new UserControllerHelper().FetchDataFromCookie(CookieField.UserRoleId.ToString());
        if (userExpire == null) 
        { 
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" }, { "Area", "" } });
        }
    }
```

And my all methods have the filter [SessionExpire]
It works fine for one session but for next click on the same action method cookies are clearing automatically.

In Global.asax i have the following code

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Timeout = 10;            
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

I tried different time outs but still no luck.

I am saving cookies with the following code

```
//create a cookie
        string cookieName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Convert.ToString(CookieField.cookieName)];
        HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        //Add key-values in the cookie
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserId), EncryptData(Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.Id)));
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserFirstName), EncryptData(Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.FirstName)));
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserLastName), EncryptData(Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.LastName)));
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserLogin), EncryptData(Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.Login)));
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserPassword), Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.LoginPassword));
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserRoleId), EncryptData(Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.RoleId)));
        userCookie.Values.Add(Convert.ToString(CookieField.UserConfirmed), Convert.ToString(userRegistrationModel.IsConfirmedByAdmin));
        //set cookie expiry date-time, if required.
        userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        //writing the cookie to client.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
```

but after a moment the "expires" automatically turning to 0. 
Is there any mistake in saving expiry date time in this code?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the filter and it resolved :)

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
    string userExpire = string.Empty;
    userExpire = new UserControllerHelper().FetchDataFromCookie(CookieField.UserRoleId.ToString());
    if (userExpire == null) 
    { 
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" }, { "Area", "" } });
    }
}
```